# Trying to figure out how to write an SQL query to return the nonintersection of two tables for a mysql database, having trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry for total noobishness, but I'm trying to write SQL for the following problem involving a mysql database and I'm at a loss.

Here's the problem.  Given the following two tables:

```
**Table1**
PID WEBSITE     COMP_SITE   KEYCODE     SITE_TYPE   KEYWORDS
14  google.com  bing.com    w3874yf8    alpha       happy+campers
26  radio.com   alice.com   98ygdsfg    beta        slip+slop
13  simon.com   fat.org     98dfyg77    delta       sunrise

**Table2**
PID WEBSITE     KEYWORDS
14  google.com  happy+campers
14  yahoo.com   fat+albert
14  aol.com     chump+change
```

I want a query to return EVERY row in **Table1** for which there are NO rows in **Table2** matching the same (ID,WEBSITE,KEYWORDS) chunk of the row.  In the above example this query would return rows 2 and 3 of **Table1**.

Note that no columns in either table containing individual values unique to the table, though the ID/WEBSITE/KEYWORDS chunk of a row will be unique.

I feel I'm making this far more complicated than it need to be. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from Table1 as t1
left join Table2 as t2 
    on  t1.PID =t2.PID
        and t1.WEBSITE  =t2.WEBSITE     
        and t1.KEYWORDS = t2.KEYWORDS
where t2.PID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways to approach this.  The first is a `left outer join`.  Use this construct to match all rows, keeping rows in the first table, and then filter out the ones with a match:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.PID = t2.PID and
        t1.WEBSITE = t2.WEBSITE and
        t1.KEYWORDS = t2.KEYWORDS
where t2.PID is null;
```

The second method is `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.PID = t2.PID and
                        t1.WEBSITE = t2.WEBSITE and
                        t1.KEYWORDS = t2.KEYWORDS
                 );
```

Both these methods can take advantage of an index on `table2`:

```
create index table2_PID_WEBSITE_KEYWORDS on table2(PID, WEBSITE, KEYWORDS);
```

Comment: Wow, after added the index the query time went from ~2 minutes to ~2 seconds.  Thanks again!